# How to make a war file with ant in groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, antbuilder

I have following script which is aim to make a war file.

```
 def ant = new AntBuilder()
 ant.ant(antfile:'build.xml', dir:APP_ROOT, target:'war')
```

unfortunately I am getting following error when groovy try to run ant.ant(... line

Error executing script War: [Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;

```
 [exec] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
 [exec]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
 [exec]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
 [exec]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$1.run(CachedClass.java:134)
 [exec]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [exec]     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:131)
```

I was wondering is there an other way to make war file with antbuilder in groovy?

Comment: I would say that `CallSite` is not in your classpath but that is to obvious isn't it? You can try `"ant".execute().waitFor()` if you just want to start ant and wait until the process finshed.

Comment: thanks for your comment CallSite is already in classpath. I guess the problem is related to version of grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem occurs if the groovy dependency of your grails is different than the groovy version installed on your local. I could reproduce the same issue when I tried to call `grails war` for a grails version dependent to Groovy 1.5 with Groovy 1.6 already installed. (BTW, Grails-1.0-RC3 is dependent to Groovy 1.5.0 and CallSite is introduced in Groovy-1.6.) When you call `grails war`, grails compiles its scripts by a wrong groovy version and fills the script cache.

To resolve this kind of issues, what I did is:

1. Removed all the files in `~/.grails/YOUR_GRAILS_VERSION/scriptCache/` folder.
2. Remove Groovy bin from path or use the correct groovy version in
   your local

Whenever you called, Grails will compile the scripts with the correct groovy version. I hope that helps.